# Can I add sequential click event to same button on same page?

Tags: javascript

I want a button to do multiple click tasks but in a sequence but when I simply add multiple 'addEventListener' it does only the last task.

```
var btn = document.querySelectorAll(".decision")[0];
var play = document.querySelector("div");
var level = 0;

btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if (level===0){
        btn.innerHTML = "Hello";
        play.innerHTML = "Click again"; //not working
        level++;
    }
    if (level===1){
        play.innerHTML = "Clicked again"; //only this is working.
        level++;    
    }
});
```

so is there any way to do this?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please visit the [help], take the [tour] to see what and [ask]. Do some research, search for related topics on SO; if you get stuck, post a [mcve] of your attempt, noting input and expected output.

Comment: Can you illustrate a little bit more your problem? Like post some code or something?

Comment: the answer is yes you can. Use a counter for example in a data-attribute

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like everything is working fine, but the second `if` is executed directly after first one, and the `innerHTML`  change is not noticeable. Please try:

```
btn.addEventListener("click",function(){
    if(level===0){
        btn.innerHTML = "Hello";
        play.innerHTML = "Click again"; //not working
        level++;
    } else if(level===1){
        play.innerHTML = "Clicked again"; //only this is working.
        level++;    
    }
})
```

Comment: is there any way to do it without a counter variable?

Comment: yes, there are a bunch of ways:
1. You can set some boolean variable like `isFirstTimeClick` and set it to true after first click.
2. You can check `play.innerHTML`, e.g. if `play.innerHTML === "Click again"` then change it.

But the approach with boolean variable seems to be better for me.